# How to link Source and target using Type with Batch

Tags: batch-file

This is very simple I know it, but I can't figure out how to get `TYPE` to connect to 
`Source` and `Target`

```
@echo off

Set "Source=%~dp0New Folder 1"
Set "Target=%~dp0New Folder 2"

type (1)_Sets.txt (2)_Sets.txt > (1).txt.tmp
ren "(1).txt.tmp"  "(1).txt"
```

I have tried many different ways and it keeps placing the files in the Main Folder

Comment: I recommend to open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `copy /?` and read the output help. What you most like need after the first three command lines are the lines `if not exist "%Source%\(1)_Sets.txt" exit /B` and `if not exist "%Source%\(2)_Sets.txt" exit /B` to check if the two source files exist and exit batch file processing if one of the two source files does not exist, `md "%Target%" 2>nul` and `if not exist "%Target%\" exit /B` to create the target directory and exit batch file processing if that failed, and as last command line ...

Comment: ... `copy /B "%Source%\(1)_Sets.txt"+"%Source%\(2)_Sets.txt" "%Target%\(1).txt"` to copy the two source files together to the target file in target directory. The __COPY__ option `/B` is necessary as otherwise the command __COPY__ would append to target file the control character EOF (End Of File) which is definitely not wanted here. Please note that source file `(1)_Sets.txt` should end with a line termination to avoid that the __string__ at end of file `(1)_Sets.txt` is merged together with first __line__ in file `(2)_Sets.txt` on one line.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested by Mofi in the comments, I wouldn't consider using the `type` command, I'd use the `copy` command.

```sh
@Set "Source=%~dp0New Folder 1"
@Set "Target=%~dp0New Folder 2"

@If Exist "%Source%\(2)_Sets.txt" If Exist "%Target%\" (
    Copy /Y /B "%Source%\(1)_Sets.txt" + "%Source%\(2)_Sets.txt" "%Target%\(1).txt"
)
```

You should note, that there is no need to check for the existence of `(1)_Sets.txt`, as the `Copy` command, *(in this format)*, will fail if the first file does not exist. You should also note that there is no need to create a target file with one name, then immediately change that name, so I just created a target file with the intended resulting name directly.

Comment: Javier Rivas, I note that you are using this answer, _(it is included in the code posted in your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66960322))_. Is there a reason why you did not therefore mark it as accepted?