# Link a wild card to a script in Batch

Tags: batch-file

Hello I was told to ask another question

I would like to see how to add this line to my current script

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%source%\(1)*.txt"') DO (
```

Or if I can get the help updating "File" and "Filename" to this `(1) *.txt` this would great as well

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 

ECHO STARTING 1

For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 1") Do Set "source=%%~fG"
For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 2") Do Set "target=%%~fG"
For %%G In ("%~dp0..\New Folder 3") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

set "FILE=(1) Homes in Texas.txt"
set "FILENAME=(1) Homes in Texas.txt"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "appi"^<"%source%\%file%"') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "opcn"^<"%source%\%file%"') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%source%\%file%"') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%target%\(A)_sets.txt"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "paid"^<"%source%\%file%" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "whbn"^<"%source%\%file%" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%source%\%file%" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%target%\(B)_sets.txt"

If Exist "%target%\*.txt" If Exist "%destdir%\" (
    Copy /Y /B "%target%\(A)_Sets.txt" + "%target%\(B)_Sets.txt" "%destdir%\(1).txt"
)

ren "%destdir%\(1).txt" "%filename%"

If Exist "%source%\(2) *.txt" (
     call "%~dp0(2) Extraction tool.bat"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Now I would like to keep this script the speed on my script is very fast it can edit my files at 1 sec per file

I'm OK with using a partial Filename

Because of my setup it makes for no errors, it's super fast speed and all files have these in the filename (?)

With the way I have my setup my workstation, I would have to edit my scripts over and over to match the file name, so I'm trying to use these (1) *.txt, because all my txt file look like this

```
Sub Houston Folder
(1) Houston.txt
(2) Houston.txt
(3) Houston.txt
Sub Auston Folder
(1) Austin.txt
(2) Austin.txt
Sub Dallas Folder
(1) Dallas.txt
(2) Dallas.txt
(3) Dallas.txt
I have over 5000 files easy
```

They all have (?) in the file name so looking for (1) *.txt, but don't know if this will be an issue with `ren "%destdir%\(1).txt" "%filename%"` using (1) *.txt

If there is a way to fix my File and Filename to work on (1) *.txt and to keep the original file name as end result that would be very appreciated

Any Help will be great

Is this correct, when I set this up this way or any other way I get blank files [corrected code below. Stephan]

```
REM not here... set "FILE=%~1"
set "FILENAME=(1) Homes in Texas.txt"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%source%\(1)*.txt"') DO call :label "%%q"
goto :eof
:Label
REM here "%~1" gets the value "%%q" from the CALL command, a FQDN (filename including drive and path because of 'dir /s /b')
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "appi"^<"%~1"') do set /a start=%%a
```

My Setup Folders

```
Main Folder
   |Extraction Batch Folder
   |New Folder 1
         |all original txt files
   |New Folder 2
         |all extracted txt files
   |New Folder 3
         |all renamed and merged files
```

It's now almost ready We got `File` fixed with that line 
still working on `Filename`

```
If Exist "%target%\*.txt" If Exist "%destdir%\" (
        Copy /Y /B "%target%\(A)_Sets.txt" + "%target%\(B)_Sets.txt" "%destdir%\(1).txt"
    )
    
    ren "%destdir%\(1).txt" "%filename%"
```

I know that wildcards does work with `ren` I tested this to confirm `*`

```
If Exist "%target%\*.txt" If Exist "%destdir%\" (
            Copy /Y /B "%target%\(A)_Sets.txt" + "%target%\(B)_Sets.txt" "%destdir%\(1).txt"
        )
        
        ren "%destdir%\(1).txt" "(*)A.txt"
```

and in `%destdir%` it rename to `(1)A.txt` so the wild card sees the `(1)` 
how can I set this up to take the matching `(1)` on the filename located in the `source` folder and use that to rename the `(1).txt` found in `%destdir% folder

Comment: @aschipfl - Hello I have my question ready

Comment: @Compo - can you help me here - trying to see if it's possible to correct `set "FILE=(1) Homes in Texas.txt"` to set `"FILE=(1) *.txt"`, and `set "FILENAME=(1) Homes in Texas.txt"` to my current script, when I try it fails

Comment: `FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%source%\(1)*.txt"') DO call :label "%%q"`. Below `:label` should be your existing code for processing one file (don't forget to change to `set "FILE=%~1"`)

Comment: @Stephan - Thank you I didn't know I had to set `File to %~1` and the reason we set it is because I have `tokens=1` is that correct

Comment: @Stephan - I can't get it to work, my files are printing in blank, I updated my question to show how I set it up

Comment: `%~1` (the first argument to the batch file or the called routine) has nothing to do with `tokens`. I corrected the code snipped in your question with some remarks to show you what and why.

Comment: OK, yes I see it now, I was thing about this section `<"%source%\%file%"` I only replaced `%File%` with `%~1` when I was testing, it didn't cross my mind that source was also not needed. Thank you it works great

Comment: @Stephan - Will you be able to help me with the `ren "%destdir%\(1).txt" "%filename%"` I'm trying to find a way to ren using `Source` file names, now that we have `File` ready

Comment: You mean "only pure filename plus extension but without the drive and path"?  `%~nx1`. See `for /?` and `call /?` what possible modifiers there are.

Comment: @Stephan - The goal was to remove the filename from the script entirely, I had 2 `SET` I had `set File` for the purpose of read and writing from a txt file and I had a `set Filename` for the purpose of doing a rename, we removed the `set File` and now I'm looking at how to remove the filename from the script on the renaming part of my script, in New Folder 1 I have all the original file names, and in New Folder 3 I have all the edited files with names like (1).txt, and (2).txt, with the `set Filename` I can rename it to match the original name, do you know if that is possible in my script

Comment: I read in cmd ren /? That you can not rename from different path

Comment: As I said: `%~nx1` is just the **N**ame and e**X**tenison of the file, without the **D**rive and  **P**ath information.

Comment: @Stephan - OK, so I got the `%~nx1` going, but with my script I have 2 print, `A_sets.txt and B_sets.txt` and I need them to be merged, the Copy /Y /B helps with that, but how can I get it to copy into the original name

Comment: OK, so how do you set up where the folders are also copied over